# How do I upload my Wordpress code files from previous website onto local host Wordpress website?

Tags: localhost, code, filesystem, wp-filesystem, file-manager

I have Wordpress code files from an old website which I downloaded from WP File Manager that I want to look at on my local host. I have downloaded Xampp and set up a local host Wordpress website.

How do I now upload the code Wordpress files that I have, in the admin section on my local host, so I can see the front end of the website from the Wordpress code files that I have?

I have tried uploading the files via WP File Manager on the local host version, but it does not work correctly, because it has all the code files from local host website, so it's duplicating.

Or is there an easier way to do it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What have you got exactly? Plugins, themes, a database export? If you've got all the files then you probably only want the wp-content folder from the download, which has plugins themes and uploaded images.

Comment: You should just be able to find the WordPress files in the xampp folders too and copy the old files there. You shouldn't have to use the admin panel and plugins for that.

Comment: @Rup I have downloaded all the files from WP File Manager

Comment: OK, I don't know the plugin but at first glance it looks like that gives you the complete WordPress install. You generally only need the wp-content folder yes. The rest will come from WordPress itself -except wp-config.php, but you'll need a new one of those for the new install anyway with new database configuration.

Comment: @Rup That didn't work unfortunately. It comes up with 'The theme directory "twentytwentythree" does not exist.'

I have installed a brand new version of wordpress, created a new database, put the new version of wordpress in the xampp/htdocs folder, then installed wordpress, then swapped the wp-content folders, so it has my original code in. 

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You will also need the database.

Comment: @JacobPeattie The website developer only has access to the database. I have admin access to the website, is there a way of getting access to the database from the Wordpress admin panel?

I only have the code files.

Comment: If you have wp-config.php in your downloads then that will contain connection information to the database - that might be worth a try, but it's probably not accessible from outside the host's network unless you have a VPN or similar mechanism too.

Comment: If you can install plugins then you can find one that will give you a database export too. Or a WordPress site export (there's one built in, or plugins) should have all the same information as well. But you should ask your developer for a database backup, there's no good reason they wouldn't give you a copy.

Comment: Missing twentytwentythree: if you want to get started with what you've got without the database then copy the theme from the new wp-content into your downloaded one. But you won't have any posts, pages, users, settings etc. as they're all in the database.

Comment: @Rup Thank you. So when I have a copy of the database, how do I add this onto Xampp? Are the code files on the database?

Comment: If it's a mysqldump then there are instructions here https://wordpress.org/support/article/restoring-your-database-from-backup/ assuming xampp has the right tools installed, but I expect it has. If you need the connection details then you can get that from your new wp-config.php.